# Cannot convert UTC to UTC+03:30 using Angular date pipe

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, datetime

In my Angular project, I have a table with a timestamp column. Its data is being filled with an HTTP request to the server.

The format in which the server sends back the timestamp is this: `2020-10-13T12:09:42.9762`

I'm trying to use the `timezone` parameter from the [angular date pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe) to format my date and show it in Iran standard time which is UTC + 3:30 like so,

```
       <tr *ngFor="let row of tableData; let i = index">
          <td>
            {{ row.timeStamp | date: 'short':'+0330' }}
          </td>
       </tr>
```

But it's not working. Only the `short` part is working in the pipe. The `+0330` part is not doing anything.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? or suggest an alternative way for converting this UTC date and time `2020-10-13T12:09:42.9762` to Iran Standard Time (IRST)? which is **UTC+03:30** by the way.

Comment: Does it work if you specify -> '+03:30' instead?

Comment: @RossBush I tried it just now. Unfortunately, it doesn't work.

Comment: You might use *toLocaleString*, e.g. `new Date().toLocaleString('en-US',{timeZone:'Asia/Tehran'})`. However, for anyone other than US users, any variant of English other than US is preferred for the language code.

Answer (score 1):

Just need add UTC designator in the end of your original date and no need to set timezone in angular date pipe

> Times are expressed in UTC (Coordinated Universal Time), with a special UTC designator ("Z")

```
{{ '2020-10-13T12:09:42.9762Z' | date:'short' }
```

if you need more information you can see date format specification of w3
[w3 time format specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime#:%7E:text=Times%20are%20expressed%20in%20UTC,mm%22%20minutes%20ahead%20of%20UTC.)